# What's the difference between css, scss, sass, and less?

Tags: html, css, sass, less

I've developed websites about two years but I've never used scss, sass, or less.  What is the difference between them and advantages of using them?

Comment: Duplicate is about Sass/.scss (and CSS) but not LESS so here it is: [LESS](http://lesscss.org) is another preprocessor with a different syntax. Also check [PostCSS](http://postcss.org) which used to be a postprocessor but is now both a pre- and postprocessor (compiles CSS to CSS - yep - and/or something close to CSS - or not, depends on the plugins you use - to CSS. Used transparently by the mighty Autoprefixer which you really _really_ should use for adding/removing vendor prefixes without human intervention thus no error :)

Comment: See also [Differences between SCSS and LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003198/differences-between-scss-and-less)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CSS is the language for styling web pages.

LESS, SASS and SCSS are pre-processors that allow a few additional features. They output a `.css` file for the website to use.